# Start new chapter on same page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters

I am using `report` document class. When I create a new chapter, it starts it on a new blank page in which only the chapter name appears.

I want to be able to start new chapters on the same page as the old chapter ends. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The `\chapter` command internally uses `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` to add page breaks. Use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to selectively change the definition of `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\chapter{bar}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Note: This `etoolbox` hack also works for the `report` class.

For `KOMA-Script` `scrbook` from version 3.19a (and most likely for other `KOMA-Script` classes, too), you need to patch `\scr@startchapter` instead of `chapter`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It is working only for the first chapter. Is it because, I have something like, \chapter{Introduction} \include{text/intro} . Is it because of the include block ? Sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: @Prakashkumar: Indeed. `\include` adds page breaks before and after it.

Comment: Is there any way to remove page breaks before and after \include because, I have separated my document into almost 30 LATEX files and I include all of them inside the parent LATEX file.

Comment: Try to use `\input` instead. See [When should I use \input vs \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for details.

Comment: So, it works now. After putting input instead of include. But another issue has come up. The Chapter names do not come in the new line. Instead some of the chapter names get attached to the content of the previous chapter.  Is there any way I can make the Chapter names appear in a new line ?

Comment: @Prakashkumar: I'm not sure what you mean with "do not come in the new line". Please edit your question and add a compilable example that shows the problem like I did in my answer. (You may have to register at tex.sx in order to edit your question.)

Comment: thank you so much ! I think earlier I was trying to put a lot of code to do the same thing. Just replacing include by input worked absolutely fine.

Comment: Using this approach in combination with the `twocolumn` documentclass option results in "Float(s) lost"...?!?

Comment: @DevSolar: The `\chapter` command is used somewhat different inside `twocolumn`, and so another approach may be needed. Please ask a new question so that other users might be able to answer (and to locate the answers.)

Comment: That would be [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34689) then, assuming it gets enough re-opening votes...

Comment: How could I do the same for a section. Meaning, if one section finishes with enough room left on the page, I would like to start the next section there. I tried just replacing `\chapter` with `\section`, but it didn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: Replacing it to `\par\relax` would be better.

Comment: With a KOMA-Script class use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443736/43317.

Comment: Not sure, but looks simulat to openany option

Comment: I have a similar problem in KOMA, but I want the part to appear on the same page as the chapter, what would I have to patch in that case?

Answer (score 81):

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{bar}}
\chapter{baz}
\end{document}
```

use `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\clearpage` for a two sided document

Comment: This worked with KOMA-Script scrbook, too.

Comment: This might not work with `\part` in scrbook (as for me)

Comment: This only affects a single chapter, right? So it would fit better to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131460/remove-pagebreak-after-a-chapter-only-for-one-chapter

Comment: I was specially struggling to put an abstract at the bottom of the first page of my report, and this did the job `\vspace*{\fill}
{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Abstract}}`

Answer (score 20):

I have used this whenever I needed to add one chapter to the previous page:

```
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{My Chapter}
\endgroup
```

It doesn't change the rest of the chapters, or anything else in the document.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as above (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24068/94816).