# No pagebreaks after chapter in report documentclass

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start new chapter on same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page)

I'm currently writing a report in the LaTeX `documentclass` `report`. The guide lines of the project I'm writing the report for state that chapters should not have their own chapter page.

Is there a setting I can pass to `documentclass` to keep this from happening?

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: [Start new chapter on same page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page). It also deals with the `report` class. Please let us know if it helped, we would close this question as a duplicate, thanks.

Comment: You may close this question, I used the wrong search terms. I too was using \include and not \input.