# Include thebibliography on the same page

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

My paper has a page limit and the spec says to include the bibliography on the same page right after the text.  I'm using the thebibliography environment (its a very simple bibliography).  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In the `article` class there's no page break before the bibliography. What class are you using?

Comment: Beautiful! I was using report -- article fixed the problem.

Answer (score 7):

In the `article` class the bibliography (either input directly as a `thebibliography` environment or prepared with the help of BibTeX or Biber) is considered as an unnumbered section, so there's no page break.

With the `report` class it is considered as a chapter, which makes sense, because the higher level of subdivision is precisely the chapter.

For a paper the `article` class is recommended. However one can obtain the same effect in `report` by following the method outlined in the answer [Start new chapter on same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page)
(although I find it disputable to have no break between the last chapter and the bibliography, because this would mean that the bibliography is relative to the last chapter only).

Take your pick.

Comment: Having no break between the last chapter and the bibliography does not mean that it is relative to the last chapter only. I currently have a short abbreviations chapter in the appendix before the bibliography, and they can go perfectly on the same page.