# Chapters on the same page or not displaying parent counters

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, koma-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start new chapter on same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page)

Using the `scrbook` class so far, what I want is either to get new chapters to start on the same page as the last one (after a reasonable amount of vertical space) or `\thesection` to display *only* the section number, not the parenting chapter number. So the following code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  
% magic packages, options   and definitions
\begin{document} 
\chapter{First chapter} % desired output: Chapter 1 – First Chapter
 Some written words. 
\chapter{Another chapter} % desired output: Chapter 2 – Another Chapter 
It's on the same page as the first chapter! 
\end{document}
```

should produce a document as explained therein, viz showing two "chapters" on the same page. I wouldn't mind to get the same result by using `\section` and packages to format sectioning like `titlesec` instead. Although I searched the documentation of several packages as well the web, I couldn't find a solution adept to my problem (the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page) doesn't work for me, probably because of the use of `scrbook`) except defining my own `\titleclass` via `titlesec` which I feel is a bit breaking a butterfly on a wheel. Should I maybe use another documentclass? (I would like to stay within koma-script classes.)

Comment: Testing one's own examples can be helpful. ;-)

Comment: The answer in the link *does* work for `scrbook` too, actually.

Comment: @lockstep It didn't for me. Wait a second. Oh, it does! Damnit. My apologies.

Comment: No problem -- I added a note to my answer, so we can close this question as a duplicate.