# Remove pagebreak after a chapter (Only for one chapter!)

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters

I am using the **report** style. I have a conclusion chapter and an acknowledgement chapter. I want to bind them together as they are both very short.

I want to remove the Pagebreak after conclusion **but only do so in this instance** so it doesn't affect other chapters. I have seen similar questions answered but they either redefine the behavior for all chapters, or don't work for the report style.

Comment: If you're using the default document class `report` (and no other extensive sectioning packages), then adding `\let\clearpage\relax` *before* your acknowledgement chapter would avoid inserting the page break... This will look weird though, since the chapter heading will still be very large. Don't you think?

Comment: I actually tried that before. but it makes the conclusion chapter ugly because It increase the line spacing. As for the weirdness, no I don't mind a large chapter heading. A one-paragraphed chapter is more weird! :)

Comment: @Shb A one paragraph conclusion chapter is useless, in my opinion. I can't understand why people always puts in the "conclusions" material that should be in the introduction.

Comment: Actually the one-paragraphed is the acknowledgement bit. But I agree, I hate all the whole formalism thing!

Comment: This question is a duplicate of question: [Start new chapter on same page][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page

Comment: @Werner: It should be noted that this solution does not precisely answer the question with the restriction "only do so in this instance so it doesn't affect other chapters". It works for one chapter, but only if that chapter is the last one. Otherwise, all following chapters are affected, too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is the simplest hack:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Conclusions}\label{chap:end}

Something.

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\chapter{Acknowledgments}\label{chap:ack}
\endgroup

I thank the people at \TeX.StackExchange for
their support.
\end{document}
```

The same if you use `\chapter*`.

Redefining both `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` is necessary only if the `openright` option is used. Otherwise acting only on `\clearpage` is sufficient, but it doesn't harm having both macros redefined.

Comment: I guess the simplest would be `\renewcommand{\newpage}{}` since both `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` depends on `\newpage`.

Comment: @Werner Right. But with the higher level macros we also avoid all checks.

Comment: I am using \chapter*. I tried doing what you suggested, but I get the same result as when I tried \let\clearpage\relax 
The line spacing in conclusion chapter becomes longer.

Comment: Oh actually it works! previously I put \endgroup after
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}
but then I tried putting it immediately after \chapter* and it works fine now.