# How to reduce spacing between titles of chapters?

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing, titlesec

I want to reduce spacing between titles of chapters. What changing should I do in the following example?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd,amsmath,latexsym,makeidx,tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{palatino,lettrine}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newenvironment{definition-new}{\begin{definition} \em}{\end{definition}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newenvironment{remark-new}{\begin{remark} \em}{\end{remark}}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newenvironment{example-new}{\begin{example} \em}{\end{example}}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newenvironment{notation-new}{\begin{notatio} \em}{\end{notatio}}
\newtheorem{agreement}[theorem]{Agreement}
\newenvironment{agreement-new}{\begin{agreement} \em}{\end{agreement}}
\def\theequation{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter \@addtoreset{equation}{section} \makeatother
\def\thefigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\makeatletter \@addtoreset{figure}{section} \makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0ex}%
 {-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex}%
{1.5ex plus 0.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\stepcounter{secnumdepth}
\stepcounter{tocdepth}
\linespread{1.8}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-.3cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{.3cm}
\stepcounter{secnumdepth}
\stepcounter{tocdepth}
\begin{document}


\chapter{Mathematical Modeling for Malaria Transmission and Chemical Control with Human         Related Activities}

\chapter{Mathematical Modeling for Malaria Transmission and Biological Control with Human Related Activities}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem. Chapters start a new page, which is normal. Do you mean the layout of chapter titles, interline spacing inside titles and the like?

Comment: If you mean a clear page between chapters, this is the default. If you don't want to have this feature, use sections instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer perhaps, as an alternative, [Remove pagebreak after a chapter (Only for one chapter!)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131460) or [Start new chapter on same page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24066), for example

Comment: @cmhughes: Well, I did not look on that questions so far, but I thought of `\relax`ing `\clearpage` ;-)

Comment: I need to reduce interline spacing inside titles.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous:

1. Spacing between titles and chapters could mean the spacing between the actual chapters.
2. It could also mean the way chapters and titles are indented.
3. It could even mean the space between body text and chapter (?).
4. Spacing *inside* the chapter title was the last I would've thought of.

---

I hope this is what you want:

I've come up with a dirty solution that suffices if you need this spacing only for some chapters (alternatively, use `\renewcommand\chapter` instead for all chapters). You can adjust line spacing inside the chapter through e.g. `\linespread{.8}` (make sure to group the value if you're using a factor with a decimal! `TeX` otherwise won't read past the first character).

Use the macro `\interlinespacing{<factor>}` for the body text.

---

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rX0occE.png?1]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd,amsmath,latexsym,makeidx,tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{palatino,lettrine}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newenvironment{definition-new}{\begin{definition} \em}{\end{definition}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newenvironment{remark-new}{\begin{remark} \em}{\end{remark}}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newenvironment{example-new}{\begin{example} \em}{\end{example}}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newenvironment{notation-new}{\begin{notatio} \em}{\end{notatio}}
\newtheorem{agreement}[theorem]{Agreement}
\newenvironment{agreement-new}{\begin{agreement} \em}{\end{agreement}}
\def\theequation{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter \@addtoreset{equation}{section} \makeatother
\def\thefigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\makeatletter \@addtoreset{figure}{section} \makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0ex}%
 {-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -0.2ex}%
{1.5ex plus 0.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\stepcounter{secnumdepth}
\stepcounter{tocdepth}
\linespread{1.8}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-.3cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{.3cm}
\stepcounter{secnumdepth}
\stepcounter{tocdepth}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mychapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
                    \linespread1%
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse%
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter%
                    %
                    }%
\def\@setsize#1#2#3#4{
\let\@currsize#1
}
\def\interlinespacing#1{
\def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \@currsize%
  \vskip \baselineskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Mathematical Modeling for Malaria Transmission and Chemical Control with Human\kern5em         Related Activities}

\mychapter{Mathematical Modeling for Malaria Transmission and Biological Control with Human Related Activities}

\interlinespacing{1.5}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `titlesec`. I redefine `\chapter`  with the `\chapterformat` and `\chapterspacing` so that it mimicks the default, but for linespacing in title. Incidentally, since I use titlesec I rewrote your modifications to `\paragraph`.

I also simplified your modifications to equation and figure numbering, using the `chngcntr` package and its `\counterwithin` command.

For the general layout, you'd better use the `geometry` package which uses parameters that are easier to understand and makes the necessary computations for you.

Let me mention that `amscd` has rather limited possibilities, and should be replaced, in my opinion, with either `tikz-cd` or the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`. A final remark: amsfonts don't go well with `palatino`; uou should consider loading `mathpazo` or `newpx` instead.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amscd,amsmath,latexsym,makeidx,tocbibind}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{palatino,lettrine}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newenvironment{definition-new}{\begin{definition} \em}{\end{definition}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newenvironment{remark-new}{\begin{remark} \em}{\end{remark}}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newenvironment{example-new}{\begin{example} \em}{\end{example}}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newenvironment{notation-new}{\begin{notatio} \em}{\end{notatio}}
\newtheorem{agreement}[theorem]{Agreement}
\newenvironment{agreement-new}{\begin{agreement} \em}{\end{agreement}}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\stepcounter{secnumdepth}
\stepcounter{tocdepth}
\linespread{1.8}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-.5cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-.3cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{.3cm}
\stepcounter{secnumdepth}
\stepcounter{tocdepth}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\raggedright\bfseries}{{\huge\chaptername~\thechapter}}{32pt}{\begin{spacing}{1.15}\Huge#1\end{spacing} }%[]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{65pt}{15pt}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{#1}%
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.2ex}

\usepackage[nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Mathematical Modeling for Malaria Transmission and Chemical Control with Human         Related Activities}

\section{A first section}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}a = b
\end{equation}

{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. }
%
\paragraph{My paragraph title }
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\chapter{Mathematical Modeling for Malaria Transmission and Biological Control with Human Related Activities}

\section{A first section}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}a = b
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

It results in these three pages:

[image]

[image]

[image]