# A question about a particular issue in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm currently writing a report using "document class report" and I would like to have a table of contents as follows:
[image]

In fact, I want to have report which every chapter has two items in the table of contents, the first with dots and page numbering, and the second without dots and page numbering. But, I do not know how to do this. I have attached my work below.

In addition to the attached picture, this is my work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{report}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph} 
\tableofcontents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{title}
This is chapter.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

How can I do that?
Thank you

Comment: Why `report` and not `article`?

Comment: What do you have so far?  What is it about your image that you would like to reproduce?  You're more likely to get better answers (and faster) if you provide the LaTeX source that is your best effort.

Comment: @ Werner, Because I have to work with  several items.

Comment: @Farid: Okay, so give us more detail about the scope of the project. Otherwise those working on solutions might provide something that doesn't fit your *needs*, but answers the *question*. Those may be two different things that we like to avoid here (since the work put into answers are free). So, help us help you.

Comment: @Werner, Actually, since I have thought this is easy, I did not attach the details. So, I am sorry. In fact, I want to have report which every chapter has two items in the table of contents, the first with dots and page numbering, and the second without dots and page numbering. But, I do not know how to do this.

I have attached my work below.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `\chapter{This is my chapter title}`?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110218/add-author-before-chapter-title-in-toc could help. Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312046/edited-book-author-chapter-and-toc/312053 ?

Comment: Are the chapters numbered? Please advise.

Comment: @ Mico 3 , Yes, they are numbered.