# Adding section header to appendix

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, appendices

I am currently using the `appendix` package and would like to add some form of header to the appendix section.

For example currently my appendix starts with Appendix A as its title, I would like it to look like

```
APPENDIX
Appendix A
Title of Appendix A
Appendix A Content

new page

Appendix B
Title of Appendix B
Appendix B Content
and so on...
```

Without a page break between the Appendix and Appendix A headers just a newline.

My current latex setup is below, inputs are just individual chapters.

```
\usepackage{appendix}
....
\begin{appendices}
\input{appendix-outline}
\end{appendices}
```

Inside the appendix-outline I have

```
\input{appendices/test1}
\input{appendices/test2}
\input{appendices/test3}
```

which are just files with a this heading

```
\chapter{test1}
text goes here
```

Comment: What do things look like inside `appendix-outline.tex`? Most likely you have `\chapter`s, correct? Do you have access to edit that file? Could you provide us with that file in the form of some dummy code?

Comment: Added whats inside the outline to main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally this is similar to [Start new chapter on same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24066/5764) as you want to avoid a page break between chapters, with the addition of **APPENDIX** before the first chapter. One could use

```
\begin{appendices}
\cleardoublepage% ...or \clearpage if you're not using the twoside option
\let\clearpage\relax
\noindent{\huge\bfseries APPENDIX\par}
\input{appendix-outline}
\end{appendices}
```

Here is a minimal example showing the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{appendix,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{appendices}
\cleardoublepage
\let\clearpage\relax
\noindent{\huge\bfseries APPENDIX\par}
\chapter{First appendix}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second appendix}
\lipsum[2]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The hope is that you don't run into problems around the page boundary inside the `appendices`. However, in such cases you might want to update `\chapter` to check the available space on the page (via something similar to what [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) provides).

Comment: That is almost what I want, I was hoping for there to still be a pagebreak after the first appendix. So after appendix A, appendix B should start on a new page.

Comment: @spoky: Then you can add `\let\oldclearpage\clearpage` to your preamble, and add `\let\clearpage\oldclearpage` *before* the second appendix. This should restore `\clearpage` to its original definition (that was saved inside `\oldclearpage` in the preamble).