# What expl3 functionality will break if the space character is redefined to have catcode 10?

Tags: expl3, latex3, white-space

What `expl3` functionality, if any, will break if I redefine the space character to have catcode 10?

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \char_set_catcode_space:n {32}
    ...
    % Does everything work as before?
    ...
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: it depends what you mean by "break" lots of examples that you copy from elsewhere will of course be written assuming normal expl3 conventions, but the workings of each command are not affected

Comment: No functionality is broken, but of course you need to take care of unwanted spaces. In `kantlipsum` I use ``\char_set_catcode_space:n {`\ }`` when the Kantian paragraphs are defined; changing spaces and newlines to `~` would be cumbersome.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: So the functions of `expl3` will work the same? How about `xparse`?

Comment: @egreg: What about formatting? Will I still be able to format the code freely? For instance adding whitspace between the arguments to a function, or placing the arguments on successive lines?

Comment: @EvanAad You can't have `\cs_new:Npn \ea_foo:nn #1 #2 {...}`, for instance, because spaces would be significant. That's an instance of what “take care of unwanted space” referred to.

Comment: no tex macro whatever package it is defined in, expl3, xparse, longtable,... is affected by the catcodes in the document once it is called, the catcodes in the document just affect how the characters in the document file are tokenized, so arguments may be tokenized differently and therefore produce a different result but the macro itself just depends on teh tokens it is passed, not the catcodes in the file (unless of course it tests the current catcode values explictly with `\ifnum\catcode32=10 yes\else no\fi`

Comment: @EvanAad The entire reason for make spaces ignored in code blocks is to allow free formatting: one of the longest-standing ideas in `expl3` (might even predate David's involvement!)

Comment: @JosephWright it does predate my involvement so before 1992 I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Things will tend to go silently wrong with little warning. The functions themselves are of course unaffected by the catcodes in the document but the spaces in the document are interpreted differently so code fragments expecting the normal context will break.

Gives me an excuse to break some of egreg's code. Suppose you had copied some code from

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24067

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn
%\catcode`\ =10\relax
  \cs_new:Npn \exampleone:nn #1 #2 {[#1 #2]}
  \cs_new:Nn \exampletwo:nn{#1 #2}

\texttt{\cs_meaning:N \exampleone:nn}\par

\texttt{\cs_meaning:N \exampletwo:nn}\par

\exampleone:nn{aa}{bb} cc dd

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

Produces

> [aabb]ccdd

which is the intended result here.

If you uncomment the catcode setting then you get

> [aabb cc]dd

which may or may not be what you expect, depending what your expectations are.