# Space between chapters

Tags: spacing, setspace

How to reduce the white space between the end of the text from a previous chapter and the begin of a new chapter?

[image]

Comment: Usually a chapter starts a new page on a recto page, so the space is just the skip above the chapter title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a (full) minimal code showing the problem?

Comment: You might be interested in [Start new chapter on same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24066/5764) (possible duplicate).