# Start new chapter on same page in two sided report class document

Tags: chapters, report, samepage

I have the settings of my document as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, outer=15mm, inner=35mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat
{\part} 
[display]
{\bfseries \huge \itshape\centering} 
{Część \ \thepart} 
{0.5ex} 
{
    \rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} 
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
] 

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\thechapter}{18pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\rfoot{Strona ~\thepage~} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{The Part name}
...
\chapter{The First Chapter name}
...
\chapter{The Second Chapter name}
...
\chapter{The Third Chapter name}
...

\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve chapters begin at the same page, just after the end of the previous chapter?
The solution from this post [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page) doesn't work in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `\clearpage`s from the `\chapter` macro. The answer is basically the same as in the link you posted, except for one detail.

You are loading `titlesec`, and apparently it expects that you enter the `\chapter` macro in "vertical mode", that is, after a paragraph. The `\clearpage` does that by default, but since you want to remove it, you have to manually insert a `\par`agraph break before `\chapter`.

#### TL;DR

Put this in your preamble and you're good to go :)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\chapter
  {\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
  {\par}% Inserting a \par here!
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, outer=15mm, inner=35mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titleformat
{\part} 
[display]
{\bfseries \huge \itshape\centering} 
{Część \ \thepart} 
{0.5ex} 
{
    \rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} 
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}
] 

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
{\thechapter}{18pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\rfoot{Strona ~\thepage~} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\chapter
  {\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}
  {\par}% Inserting a \par here!
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{The Part name}
...
\chapter{The First Chapter name}
...
\chapter{The Second Chapter name}
...
\chapter{The Third Chapter name}
...

\end{document}
```