# Strange empty page after \chapter in appendix

Tags: koma-script, appendices, emptypage

In my appendix a strange empty page is appearing. These are the packages I am using and a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot,ngerman,headsepline,bibliography=toc]{scrreprt} 
%KOMA-Skript-Klasse: scrreprt
%
%
%
%
% #######################################################################
% Packages
% #######################################################################
%Grafik und Layout
%--------------------------
\usepackage{hyph}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[superscripts]{cite}
% Naturwissenschaftliche Bibliographien
\usepackage[square, comma, numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % geändert auf utf8
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Neu 230318
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{afterpage}% \afterpage{\clearpage} um float-Speicher zurückzusetzten
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Veränderung des Zeilenabstands
%\usepackage{calc}          % Für BErechnungen von Latexkomandos
%\usepackage{verbatim} % Für Code-Umgebungen
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{float,rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=below}
\captionsetup{format=hang, labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off, labelfont=bf, textfont=normalfont}
%Schriftarten
%------------------------
\usepackage{ae}
%Programmcode einbinden
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=c++}
\lstset{stepnumber=1}
\lstset{showstringspaces=false}
\lstset{frame=single}
\lstset{breaklines=true}
\lstset{captionpos=b}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}
{Code snippet}
\lstset{basicstyle=\tiny ,} % =\tiny =\ttfamily
\lstset{numbers=left}
%
%Fremdsprachen
%------------------------
\usepackage[english]{babel} % ngerman für deutsch english für englische Tabellen, figures usw..
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%Abstände
% Ändern der Abstände subsection...
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.25\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
%Abbildungen
%------------------------
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%
%Formeln und Gleichungen
%------------------------
% amsmath und amsfonts neu
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{stmaryrd} %definiert u.a. \minuso als Symbol für Standardbedingungen
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
%Literatur
%------------------------ 
%\addbibresource{Forschungsarbeit.bib}

% Zitationsstil
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%Silbentrennung
%------------------------
%\usepackage{hyph}
%%\usepackage{boxit} ###############################################################
% Formateinstellung                                             #% Neudefinition der Schriftart der ï¿½berschriften (KOMA-Skript)
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}
%\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily \bfseries} ###############################################################
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%------------------------
% Nummerierungstiefe bis Ebene
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}
% Nummerierungstiefe im Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setcounter{tocdepth}{10}
%
%
%
%Hyperlinks
%------------------------
%nur bei Ausgabeform LaTeX => PDF aktivieren
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
pdfstartview=FitB,
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
plainpages=false}
\begin{document}

\appendix
  \include{Anhang_Normal} %Aktivieren zum Einfügen!
\end{document}
```

This is my appendix:

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\label{Anhang}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} % Add Appendix to TOC
\thispagestyle{empty}
ddldldl Blublalb Blublalb
\chapter{Physical properties}
\label{anhang_a}

Blublalb Blublalb Blublalb
```

What I would like to have on one page:

**Appendix**

**A: Physical properties**

Text
Text
Text

Comment: Dirty hack: `{
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\chapter{Physical properties}
}`

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24068/36296