# Make TeXstudio not break the page at a new chapter

Tags: page-breaking, chapters

I'm having trouble using TeXstudio with the template of my university (see code below). I need to use the command `\chapter` for every new chapter (obviously), so the numbering won't start with `0` because the `documentclass` is `scrbook`. Apparently I'm using a KOMA-script based document class.

My issue now is, everytime a new chapter is opened, TeXstudio clears the whole page, which leaves big gaps inbetween the end of the current chapter and the beginning of the new one.

How can I fix that, so that the new chapter begins right after the current one on the same page?

If anyone asks, no I am not able to use another package/template or something else. We have to use this template for our bachelor thesis. I just wanna change this one problem!

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openany, DIV15, BCOR15mm]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=empty}
%
% Packages
\usepackage{hanser}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\parindent0.0cm
\parskip1.5ex

\bibliographystyle{geralpha}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}


\definecolor{codecolor}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\lstloadlanguages{[ANSI]C++, Java}
\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily \small}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{codecolor}}
\lstset{extendedchars=true} \lstset{showstringspaces = false}

\raggedbottom
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[L, RO]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small \nouppercase  \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} %
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %
}

\setlength\abovecaptionskip          {0.4em}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip          {0.2em}

\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.99}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\title{Aufbau eines Ticketsystems (Arbeitstitel)}
\date{11.~Juli~2018}
\author{, }
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Allow me to ask for confirmation, because a thesis in which chapters do not start on a new page is *very* uncommon: do you mean that your university insist on you using the assigned template, and then permits you to deviate from tradition on an aspect like that?  Are you sure you are not confusing `\chapter`s with `\section`s?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TeXStudio, TeXStudio is an editor which calls LaTeX to generate a PDF for you. Sine you do not show what `...` is, we cannot quite help. Please make a complete example

Comment: @daleif in the dots there are just \input commands. this is the complete template file, other than that

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24067/36296

Comment: It still means that the MWE is not complete.

Comment: i literally have no idea what that means

Comment: We have no clue what your document looks like. https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/How_to_get_help

Comment: theres just two \chapter commands after each other which are 2 sites apart cause latex blanks out one page in between. thats it

Comment: @Suimon The point is that the code that you post in your question should reproduce your problem when we run it on our systems. (Here, it's called a minimal working example, or MWE said by @daleif). Right now, the content inside `...` should also be provided, at the very least. If we can't reproduce your problem, how do you expect anyone to help?

Comment: @Troy heres the code:

\chapter{chapter1}
\chapter{chapter2}