# Latex/scrbook - no pagebreak above chapter

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, chapters, koma-script, scrbook

My problem is that I need to start new chapters on the same page if there is still space available. I use the scrbook class.
As far as I see I have two solutions.
1. Change the class, i.e. to scrarticle and lose out on having chapters
2. adding selectively:

```
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{My Chapter}
\endgroup
```

or I can do the same for the whole document with:

```
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
```

But if I do this Latex is all fact up and kind of ignores its nice visual pleasing features, see the picture. I need to mention that I use for each chapter and their sections a new latex file, while adding them with \input into a main document.

What am I doing wrong. If I need to resort to manually adding spaces at the end of the last chapter,  how much vertical space should I add?

I [image: problem]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457713  There are two suggestions: `style=section` for the `\chapter` command and alternatively the declaration of a new sectioning command.

Answer (score 5):

Technically no problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
style=section]
{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\label{CLA:first-chapter}

\blindtext{}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\label{CLA:second-chapter}

\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

But why? A chapter is more or less by definition a section of a text that starts on a new page.

If you only need to add more levels under section, subsection, subsub... you may add as much levels as you need, see `\DeclareNewSectionCommand`in the KOMA-script manual.

Comment: I have been looking for a solution for hours. Only thing that worked for me...