# chapter title not appear on a single page

Tags: sectioning

I am currently using report document class and include chapters and the titles appears on a single page, how the title showed up exactly after previous chapter?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! You are probably looking for the `openany` option to the documentclass.  If that does not work, then please post the code of a minimal document demonstrating your problem.

Comment: `\chapter`s in the `report` class start on a new page. Depending on the options (`openany`, `openright`) a new chapter may start only on odd pages (leaving a completely empty page if necessary) or on all pages. If you don't even want to start a new page, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24066/35864