# How to stop chapters starting a new page

Tags: chapters, titles, books

How can I achieve that chapters do not start on a new page? Below you find a small example document, where I would like that the titles are all in one page. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
    
    
    
    \makeatletter
    \makeatother
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    
    
    
    
    \titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries \centering \sffamily}{\huge \Roman{chapter}.}{10pt}{\huge}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \chapter{title1}
    \chapter{title2}
    \chapter{title3}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24067/134144 might be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `titlesec`, `\chapter` can be made a `straight` sectioning class (that is, a sectioning command which starts the new section without any page break) with the `\titleclass` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\centering\sffamily}{\huge\Roman{chapter}.}{10pt}{\huge}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title1}
\chapter{title2}
\chapter{title3}

\end{document}
```

[image]