# Delete empty page

Tags: chapters, tufte-book

I have the next output:

[image: Output]

And I want the text to start right after the box, even if is a chapter.

I have tried `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` command but doesn't work.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

 \usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
% matemáticas:
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\usepackage{physics}
% idioma:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % 'cuadro' es el título del caption de table por defecto siguiendo indicaciones de RAE; es-tabla lo cambia a 'tabla'
% gestión de párrafos (hace innecesario indicar el salto de línea con doble barra y elimina el indent de todos los párrafos):
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff} 
  
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=gray,citecolor=gray,urlcolor=gray,breaklinks]{hyperref} % changed <<<<<<
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} 



%%******************************************************************** Changed 
\newcommand{\CourseName}{MT2223: Real analysis-I} % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\CourseSemester}{Jan-May 2022}  % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\CourseInstructor}{Praphulla Koushik}    % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\listlecturename}{Clases \hfill {\footnotesize Página \par}} % title of the list <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlistof[part]{lecture}{lec}{\listlecturename} % define list of lectures

\newcounter{lecnum}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}
\newcommand{\lecture}[2]{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< use as  \lecture{number}{date}
    \pagestyle{myheadings}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \refstepcounter{lecture}
    \addcontentsline{lec}{lecture}{Clase~#1:~#2}
    \noindent
    \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \begin{fullwidth}
        \centering\vspace{2mm}
        {\bfseries\CourseName \hfill \CourseSemester
         \vspace{4mm}\\ 
         \Large \hfill  Clase #1  \hfill }
         \vspace{4mm}\\  
         {\normalfont Date: #2 \hfill  Profesor:~\CourseInstructor}
         \vspace{2mm}
         \end{fullwidth}
    \end{minipage}
    
    }



\title{Tufte book}
\author{Álvaro Méndez Rodríguez de Tembleque}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\listoflecture 
\tableofcontents
\lecture{1}{Enero 30}

\chapter{Hola}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, but this is not a MWE: we should be able to compile it, and here there is no `documentclass`, no packages...

Comment: @Rmano Sorry, I have changed

Comment: Still wrong, sorry. Did you test it? Why two blocks? Please change your question with **a single piece of code** that we can copy, paste and compile. I have a `Runaway argument? {\pagestyle {myheadings} ...` error; after that, all bets are off. Please dedicate a bit of your time to preparing a viable example, so we can spend a bit of our time in finding the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Now you have everything I hope

Comment: @alvaritomendez There are some `\newcommand` and some packages that aren't used. Also your example won't give the blank page you mentioned. MWE means minimal (avoid irrelevant stuffs) and should also help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most document classes have an `openany` option that will omit blank pages at the ends of major divisions.  This means that pages beginning chapters may no longer always start on a right-hand page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After:

1. removing all the clashing packages (I did not look why and where they clashed; you should have take care of that when adding the package); they are

   - geometry
   - eucal
   - xcolor
   - hyperref
     The thing compiled.

Then,

2. removing the extra spaces at the end of the line in the command `\lecture`
3. [adding `openany` option to the class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128336/38080)

Now the extra page is gone.

Notice that I do not advise using this as-is. Remove *all* packages and add them only when you need them, and find *why* someone clashes (probably `tufte-book` has already loaded most of them). For example, the last time `epsfig` was needed I think was around 1985. A rule of thumb is that you should exactly know why you load any package.

[image]

Minimally patched code here:

```latex
\documentclass[openany]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

 \usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
% matemáticas:
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
% idioma:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % 'cuadro' es el título del caption de table por defecto siguiendo indicaciones de RAE; es-tabla lo cambia a 'tabla'
% gestión de párrafos (hace innecesario indicar el salto de línea con doble barra y elimina el indent de todos los párrafos):
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}

% \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=gray,citecolor=gray,urlcolor=gray,breaklinks]{hyperref} % changed <<<<<<
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}



%%******************************************************************** Changed
\newcommand{\CourseName}{MT2223: Real analysis-I} % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\CourseSemester}{Jan-May 2022}  % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\CourseInstructor}{Praphulla Koushik}    % fill <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand{\listlecturename}{Clases \hfill {\footnotesize Página \par}} % title of the list <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlistof[part]{lecture}{lec}{\listlecturename} % define list of lectures

\newcounter{lecnum}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thelecnum-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecnum.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thelecnum.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecnum.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thelecnum.\arabic{table}}
\newcommand{\lecture}[2]{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< use as  \lecture{number}{date}
    \pagestyle{myheadings}%
    \newpage
    \setcounter{lecnum}{#1}%
    \setcounter{page}{1}%
    \refstepcounter{lecture}%
    \addcontentsline{lec}{lecture}{Clase~#1:~#2}%
    \noindent
    \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \begin{fullwidth}%
        \centering\vspace{2mm}
        {\bfseries\CourseName \hfill \CourseSemester
         \vspace{4mm}\\
         \Large \hfill  Clase #1  \hfill }
         \vspace{4mm}\\
         {\normalfont Date: #2 \hfill  Profesor:~\CourseInstructor}
         \vspace{2mm}
         \end{fullwidth}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \par
}}



\title{Tufte book}
\author{Álvaro Méndez Rodríguez de Tembleque}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\listoflecture
\tableofcontents
\lecture{1}{Enero 30}

\chapter{Hola}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This one is great but I want the text to start as the lecture box is finished, right under there. I will make that adjustment but thanks for the awnser

Comment: @alvaritomendez I do not know the details of the `tufte-book` class. Normally any class has chapters starting a new page. Often when somebody wants chapters "inline" it means that it should not use chapters; maybe a class with just sections will do. Otherwise, you can [check the `titlesec` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550637/how-to-stop-chapters-starting-a-new-page) but I do not know if it's compatible with `tufte` or the strange mix of packages you are loading.