# Beginning a New Chapter Not Necessarily on a New Page

Tags: chapters, page, samepage

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{1}}
\lipsum[13]
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{2}}
\lipsum[19]
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{3}}
\lipsum[13]
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{4}}
\lipsum[19]
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

[image]

Here, a new chapter *always* begins on a new page. I would change this.

QUESTION: How may I begin a new chapter on the same page (space permitting) that the previous chapter ended *(i)* on a selective basis (i.e., for only certain chapters); and *(ii)*, on a global basis (i.e., for all chapters)?

Thank you.

Comment: For the `book` class, a new `\chapter` usually starts on a new page. Have you considered using `\section` with, say, the article class? That said, if you must, this should help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following hack works in your case:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{\par}{}{}
```

[image]

The complete code is

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{\par}{}{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{1}}
\lipsum[13]
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{2}}
\lipsum[19]
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{3}}
\lipsum[13]
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{4}}
\lipsum[19]
\end{document}
```