# Part title on the same page as the next chapter

Tags: formatting, chapters, parts

tl;dr: How do I prevent a Part's title from taking the entire page? I want to place it on the same page as the next chapter's title.

I'm writing a dissertation, and it has several parts. I got the following comment for the revision:

> Remove pages that are intro pages for sections. Intro pages are those that have only the chapter/section title and very little other information on the page. Instead, place this information on the first page of the actual page of the chapter/section. ... This is in reference to pages ...

While they call the parts "chapters/sections", they explicitly refer to the pages where the parts start.

How to fix: I want to place the part on the same page as the next chapter. I.e. I want a page like this:

> Part I
>
> FOO
>
> Chapter 1
>
> Bar
>
> ...contents...

How do I do that? My document class is `report`, and I don't plan on changing that.

I found questions about removing page breaks between chapters ([Start new chapter on same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page)), which doesn't work since Part has significantly different formatting.

Comment: The titlesec package documentation has an example that does this in section 8, if memory serves.

Comment: Please provide your code what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I modify `\part` to set a `\chapter*`, but using the `part` counter representation. An update to `\chapter` also temporarily removes the `\clearpage` functionality to avoid setting the chapter on the following page. You don't specify anything about the need for parts in your ToC, but this could be added if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifpart
\let\oldpart\part% Store original \part (may not be necessary)
\RenewDocumentCommand{\part}{ m }{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \refstepcounter{part}%
  \chapter*{% Set \part as a \chapter*
    Part~\thepart \endgraf
    \vspace{20pt}%
    #1%
  }%
  \vspace{-40pt}% Remove some vertical space to next \chapter
  \parttrue% A \part has been set
}
\let\oldchapter\chapter% Store original \chapter
\let\oldclearpage\clearpage% Store original \clearpage
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s o m}{%
  \ifpart% If a \part has been set
    \let\clearpage\relax% Remove \clearpage functionality temporarily
  \fi
  % Now set a regular \chapter
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldchapter*{#3}}% \chapter*{..}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
      {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}% \chapter[.]{..}
      {\oldchapter{#3}}% \chapter{..}
    }%
  \let\clearpage\oldclearpage% Restore \clearpage functionality
  \partfalse% No \part has been set
}

\begin{document}

\part{First part}

\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\quad#1}` for the TOC entry